# Resolve two artifacts in same dependency using ivy

Tags: java, ant, apache-kafka, ivy

I'm having trouble resolving kafka dependencies using ivy.

I am trying to create a kafka server in a junit test.

`TestUtils.createServer(kafkaConfig, Time.SYSTEM);`

This requires `kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1.jar`, `kafka-clients-0.10.2.1-test.jar`, and `kafka_2.11-0.2.1-test.jar` to be on the test class path since `kafka.utils.TestUtils` is in the `*-test.jar`. The problem is how can I resolve the `*-test.jar` using ivy and ant? In the `ivy.xml` I have:

```
<configurations defaultconfigmapping="default>
    <conf name="compile"/>
    <conf name="test" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="master"/>
    <conf name="sources"/>
    <conf name="javadoc"/>
    <conf name="runtime" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="default" extends="master,runtime"/>
</configurations>
...
    <dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka-clients" rev="0.10.2.1" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka_2.11" rev="0.10.2.1" conf="test->default">
        <artifact name="kafka_2.11" ext="jar"/>
        <artifact name="kafka_2.11" e:classifier="test" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka-clients" rev="0.10.2.1" conf="test->default">
        <artifact name="kafka-clients" ext="jar"/>
        <artifact name="kafka-clients" e:classifier="test" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>
```

The build has something similar this

```
<ivy:resolve log="quiet" conf="compile" transitive="false"/>
<ivy:cachepth pathid="test-classpath" conf="test" log="quiet"/>
```

This results in `NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils`.

I noticed that conf is set to "compile" but when I add test to the list I get other errors for missing classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the transitive dependency resolution to false. You'll lose one of the major benefits of using ivy.

Instead create configuration mappings in each of your dependencies.

## Example

The following contrived example saves the dependencies in separate directories to illustrate which jars are on the desired classpath. As you can see the kafka client jars are downloaded along with the jars they depend on (the transitive dependencies).

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── target
    └── lib
        ├── compile
        │   ├── kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar
        │   ├── lz4-1.3.0.jar
        │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
        │   └── snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar
        └── test
            ├── kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar
            ├── kafka-clients-test-0.10.2.1.jar
            ├── lz4-1.3.0.jar
            ├── slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
            └── snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar
```

### build.xml

The retrieve task is used to save the files under the "target/lib" directory. The ivycachepath task is used to create an ANT cache with the appropriate files.

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="build">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/lib/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile-classpath" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test-classpath" conf="test"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

The magic is in the configuration mappings "compile->default" or "test->default".

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="test" description="Additional test dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka-clients" rev="0.10.2.1" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka-clients" rev="0.10.2.1" conf="test->default">
            <artifact name="kafka-clients"/>
            <artifact name="kafka-clients" e:classifier="test"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: I completely agree with the transitive="false". I'm trying to figure out how and why it was changed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since cachepath is a post resolve task doesn't it cause the transitives to be downloaded anyway? It seems like transitives are somehow getting resolved even with transitive="false". This is the only call to resolve in the build phase too.

Comment: @JohnMercier You are correct it is a post resolve task. I normally make a single call to the "resolve" task without arguments (all configurations) to get it out of the way at the beginning of the build. The cachepath tasks will not resolve a second time. It sounds like you want to stop the downloading of all transitive dependencies? I would suggest optimizing elsewhere, you'll have more joy. For example I run Sonatype Nexus locally to cache all binaries from Maven Central, and point my Maven and ANT builds at that.

Comment: Oh I agree completely. This is a false optimization which causes all sorts of dependency hell. The problem is political. Trying to convince the tribal elders there is a fundamental problem in their monolithic build system will not be easy. I'm just trying to learn what the problem is so every time I have to add dependencies due to improved test coverage I can point out the real problem.